# How can I deploy a simple Spring Boot Application JAR file to a Wildfly 10 Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly

I am trying to find a solution for deploying the Spring Boot application to a Wildfly server. There are some deployments with WAR files before in some paths: /hello1, /hello2. My target is to deploy on /hello3 so I have created src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml with these content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/hello3</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I have also created an endpoint "/" which return "Hello World" in localhost:8080 after running spring boot. But the server keeps returning 404 not found. The server works fine on /hello1 and /hello2.

Comment: Do you package `Spring Boot Application` as `jar` or `war`? `Create a Deployable War File` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

Comment: I am deploying using JAR file

Comment: use war file, `How to Deploy Spring Boot Applications to WildFly Application Server` (https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-09/spring-boot--wildfly/#gsc.tab=0)